# How do i read a csv file with time in AM and PM in julia

Tags: julia

I am using Julia CSV and I am trying to read data with DateTime in the form `10/17/2012 12:00:00 AM` i tried

```
dfmt = dateformat"mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS"
data =CSV.File("./Fremont_Bridge_Bicycle_Counter.csv", dateformat=dfmt) |> DataFrame
println(first(data,8))
```

but the thing is that I think the AM and PM makes the string not recognized as a date can someone help show how to pass this as a date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `p` specifier, which matches AM or PM.  With that, your date format would look like this:

```
dfmt = dateformat"mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS p"
```

You can see that the parsing is correct:

```
julia> DateTime("10/17/2012 12:00:00 AM", dfmt)
2012-10-17T00:00:00
```

To see all the possible format characters, check out [the docstring of `Dates.DateFormat`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/#Dates.DateFormat), which is accessible in the REPL through `?DateFormat`.

Comment: thankyou.. this works fine when used in normal string though but not in the read CSV but for now, I think I will have to subset the date column and use this format in the map function then replace the date with the new column values

Comment: You might have to pass `dateformat` as a `String`... never having fiddled with dates, I'm afraid I don't know much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

With the file Fremont_Bridge_Bicycle_Counter.csv

```
N1, N2, fecha
hola, 3, 10/03/2020 10:30:00
pepe, 5, 10/03/2020 11:40:50
juan, 5, 03/04/2020 20:10:12
```

And with the julia code:

```
using DataFrames, Dates, CSV

dfmt = dateformat"mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS p"
data =CSV.File("./Fremont_Bridge_Bicycle_Counter.csv", dateformat=dfmt) |> DataFrame
println(first(data,8))
```

It gives the right result:

```
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ N1     │  N2   │  fecha              │
│     │ String │ Int64 │ DateTime            │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ hola   │ 3     │ 2020-10-03T10:30:00 │
│ 2   │ pepe   │ 5     │ 2020-10-03T11:40:50 │
│ 3   │ juan   │ 5     │ 2020-03-04T20:10:12 │
```

Comment: Your data date does not contain the AM and Pm try adding it and see the output on fecha. in your case, your the data dates are 24hr but the set I have has 12hr system with am and pm extension. please see the time format I gave in the question